# How to fix wrong constructor parameters in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have an interesting error with reflections in kotlin.

So, im using 'argTypes' method for getting all parameter type of args.

```
private fun argTypes(vararg args: Any): Array<Class<*>> {
        val argTypes = ArrayList<Class<*>>()
        args.forEach { argTypes.add(it::class.java) }
        return argTypes.toTypedArray()
    }
```

Im using it with like that:

```
fun <T> newInstance(clazz: Class<*>, argTypes: Array<Class<*>>, vararg args: Any): T {
        return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(*argTypes).newInstance(*args) as T
    }
```

In the end:

```
ReflectionUtil.instance.newInstance<IBossBar>(
                PacketBossBar1_13_R2::class.java,
                TextComponent("asd"),Color.BLUE,Style.PROGRESS,100F)
```

I use a float parameters thats '100F'.

When i use that method, the type is going to be java.lang.Float but my 'PacketBossBar1_13_R2' constructor has a float parameters like that:

```
constructor(
            message: TextComponent,
            color: Color,
            style: Style,
            progress: Float
    ): this(ComponentSerializer.toString(message), color, style, progress)
```

When i getting the constructor as a manual, its return

```
public io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.nms.v1_13_R2.PacketBossBar1_13_R2(net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent,io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Color,io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Style,float)
```

When i use automatic way its returning NoSucMethodException like that:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.nms.v1_13_R2.PacketBossBar1_13_R2.<init>(net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent, io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Color, io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Style, java.lang.Float)
```

Also my ReflectionUtil and PackateBossBar classes:

```
package io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.misc

import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.lang.reflect.Method
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
import java.util.*
import java.util.stream.Collectors

class ReflectionUtil {

    private val nmsVersion: String
        get() = nms().split("\\.".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()[3]

    val craftBukkitVersion: String
        get() = cb().split("\\.".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()[3]

    private fun nms(): String {
        return exec<Any>(Bukkit.getServer(), "getServer").javaClass.getPackage().name
    }

    private fun cb(): String {
        return Bukkit.getServer().javaClass.getPackage().name
    }

    fun getPackageName(nmsObject: Any): String {
        return nmsObject.javaClass.getPackage().name
    }

    fun getBukkitClass(craftObject: Any): Class<*> {
        var clazz: Class<*> = craftObject.javaClass
        while (clazz.canonicalName.contains(".craftbukkit.")) {
            clazz = clazz.superclass
        }
        return clazz
    }

    fun getCustomBukkitClass(className: String): Class<*> {
        return Class.forName("org.bukkit.craftbukkit.$nmsVersion.$className")
    }

    fun getNMSClass(name: String): Class<*> {
        return Class.forName("net.minecraft.server.$nmsVersion.$name")
    }


    fun <T> execStatic(clazz: Class<*>, methodName: String, vararg args: Any): T {
        val method = getMethod(clazz, methodName, *argTypes(*args))
        val wasAccessible = method.isAccessible
        method.isAccessible = true
        try {
            return method.invoke(null, *args) as T
        } finally {
            method.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun <T> execStatic(clazz: Class<*>, methodName: String, argTypes: Array<Class<*>>, vararg args: Any): T {
        val method = getMethod(clazz, methodName, *argTypes)
        val wasAccessible = method.isAccessible
        method.isAccessible = true
        try {
            return method.invoke(null, *args) as T
        } finally {
            method.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun <T> exec(obj: Any, methodName: String, argTypes: Array<Class<*>>, vararg args: Any): T {
        val aClass = obj.javaClass
        val method = getMethod(aClass, methodName, *argTypes)
        val wasAccessible = method.isAccessible
        method.isAccessible = true

        try {
            return method.invoke(obj, *args) as T
        } finally {
            method.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun getMethod(aClass: Class<*>, methodName: String, vararg argTypes: Class<*>): Method {
        return aClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *argTypes)
    }

    fun findMethod(aClass: Class<*>, returnType: Class<*>, vararg argTypes: Class<*>): Method {
        return findMethods(aClass, returnType, *argTypes)[0]
    }

    fun findMethods(aClass: Class<*>, returnType: Class<*>, vararg argTypes: Class<*>): List<Method> {
        val methods = ArrayList<Method>()
        for (m in aClass.declaredMethods) {
            if (m.returnType == returnType && m.parameterTypes.size == argTypes.size) {
                val mLookup = aClass.getMethod(m.name, *argTypes)

                if (mLookup != null) methods.add(mLookup)
            }
        }
        return methods
    }

    fun <T> exec(obj: Any, methodName: String, vararg args: Any): T {
        return exec(obj, methodName, argTypes(*args), *args) as T
    }

    fun <T> getField(clazz: Class<*>, fieldName: String): T {
        val field = getFieldFromClass(clazz, fieldName)
        val wasAccessible = field.isAccessible
        field.isAccessible = true
        try {
            return field.get(null) as T
        } finally {
            field.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun <T> getField(obj: Any, fieldName: String): T {
        val field = getFieldInternal(obj, fieldName)
        val wasAccessible = field.isAccessible
        field.isAccessible = true
        try {
            return field.get(obj) as T
        } finally {
            field.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun getFieldInternal(obj: Any, fieldName: String): Field {
        return getFieldFromClass(obj.javaClass, fieldName)
    }

    fun getFieldFromClass(aClass: Class<*>, fieldName: String): Field {
        return try {
            aClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
        } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
            try {
                aClass.getField(fieldName)
            } catch (e1: NoSuchFieldException) {
                getFieldFromClass(aClass.superclass, fieldName)
            }
        }
    }

    fun setField(obj: Any, fieldName: String, field: Any?) {
        val declaredField = getFieldInternal(obj, fieldName)
        val wasAccessible = declaredField.isAccessible
        declaredField.isAccessible = true
        try {
            declaredField.set(obj, field)
        } finally {
            declaredField.isAccessible = wasAccessible
        }
    }

    fun <T> newInstance(clazz: Class<*>, argTypes: Array<Class<*>>, vararg args: Any): T {
        return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(*argTypes).newInstance(*args) as T
    }

    fun <T> newInstance(clazz: Class<*>, vararg args: Any): T {
        return newInstance(clazz, argTypes(*args), *args)
    }

    fun <T> newInstance(className: String, vararg args: Any): T {
        return newInstance(className, argTypes(*args), *args)
    }

    private fun argTypes(vararg args: Any): Array<Class<*>> {
        val argTypes = ArrayList<Class<*>>()
        args.forEach { argTypes.add(it::class.java) }
        return argTypes.toTypedArray()
    }

    fun dumpMethods(aClass: Class<*>): List<String> {
        val methods = aClass.declaredMethods
        val methodDescriptions = ArrayList<String>()
        val version = nmsVersion
        for (m in methods) {
            var parmString = Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(m.parameterTypes).map<String>{ it.name }.toArray())
            parmString = parmString.substring(1, parmString.length - 1)
            var description = ((if (Modifier.isPublic(m.modifiers)) "public " else if (Modifier.isPrivate(m.modifiers)) "private " else "")
                    + (if (Modifier.isStatic(m.modifiers)) "static " else "")
                    + m.returnType + " " + m.name
                    + "(" + parmString + ")")
            description = description
                    .replace("class net.minecraft.server.$version.".toRegex(), "")
                    .replace("net.minecraft.server.$version.".toRegex(), "")
                    .replace("java.lang.".toRegex(), "")
            methodDescriptions.add(description)
        }
        val list = ArrayList<String>()

        list.add(aClass.toString().replace("class net.minecraft.server.$version.".toRegex(), "")
                .replace("net.minecraft.server.$version.".toRegex(), "")
                .replace("java.lang.".toRegex(), "") + ":")
        list.addAll(methodDescriptions.stream().sorted { obj, anotherString -> obj.compareTo(anotherString) }.collect(Collectors.toList()))
        return list
    }

    companion object {
        val instance = ReflectionUtil()
    }

}
```

````
package io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.nms.v1_13_R2

import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.addBossBarForPlayer
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Color
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Property
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.enums.Style
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.bossbar.removeBossBarForPlayer
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.misc.ReflectionUtil
import io.github.utsukushihito.utsutil.api.nms.IBossBar
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent
import net.md_5.bungee.chat.ComponentSerializer
import net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.BossBattle
import net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.IChatBaseComponent
import net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R2.PacketPlayOutBoss
import org.bukkit.Location
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.entity.CraftPlayer
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import java.util.*

class PacketBossBar1_13_R2(
        private var message: String,
        private var color: Color,
        private var style: Style,
        private var progress: Float,
        vararg properties: Property
) : IBossBar{

    private val receivers = ArrayList<Player>()

    private val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()

    private var darkenSky: Boolean = false
    private var playMusic: Boolean = false
    private var createFog: Boolean = false
    private var visible: Boolean = false

    constructor(
            message: TextComponent,
            color: Color,
            style: Style,
            progress: Float,
            vararg properties: Property
    ): this(ComponentSerializer.toString(message), color, style, progress, *properties)

    // I Try to run this cotr with the reflection util.
    constructor(
            message: TextComponent,
            color: Color,
            style: Style,
            progress: Float
    ): this(ComponentSerializer.toString(message), color, style, progress)

    init {
        setMessage(message)
        setProgress(progress)
        properties.forEach {
            setProperty(it,true)
        }
    }

    override fun getPlayers(): Collection<Player> {
        return ArrayList(this.receivers)
    }

    override fun addPlayer(player: Player) {
        if (!receivers.contains(player)) {
            receivers.add(player)
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.ADD, player)
            player.addBossBarForPlayer(this)
        }
    }

    override fun removePlayer(player: Player) {
        if (receivers.contains(player)) {
            receivers.remove(player)
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.REMOVE, player)
            player.removeBossBarForPlayer(this)
        }
    }

    override fun getColor(): Color {
        return color
    }

    override fun setColor(color: Color) {
        if (color != this.color) {
            this.color = color;
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.UPDATE_STYLE, null);
        }
    }

    override fun getStyle(): Style {
        return style
    }

    override fun setStyle(style: Style) {
        if (style != this.style) {
            this.style = style
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.UPDATE_STYLE, null)
        }
    }

    override fun setProperty(property: Property, flag: Boolean) {
        when (property) {
            Property.DARKEN_SKY -> darkenSky = flag
            Property.PLAY_MUSIC -> playMusic = flag
            Property.CREATE_FOG -> createFog = flag
        }
        sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.UPDATE_PROPERTIES, null)
    }

    override fun setMessage(message: String) {
        if (!message.startsWith("{") || !message.endsWith("}")) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid JSON")
        }
        if (message != this.message) {
            this.message = message
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.UPDATE_NAME, null)
        }
    }

    override fun getMessage(): String {
        return message;
    }

    override fun setVisible(flag: Boolean) {
        if (flag != this.visible) {
            this.visible = flag
            sendPacket(if (flag) PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.ADD else PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.REMOVE, null)
        }
    }

    override fun isVisible(): Boolean {
        return visible
    }

    override fun getProgress(): Float {
        return progress
    }

    override fun setProgress(progress: Float) {
        if (progress > 1) this.progress = progress / 100F

        if (progress != this.progress) {
            this.progress = progress
            sendPacket(PacketPlayOutBoss.Action.UPDATE_PCT, null)
        }
    }

    private fun sendPacket(action: PacketPlayOutBoss.Action, player: Player?) {
        try {
            val packet = PacketPlayOutBoss()
            val ref = ReflectionUtil.instance

            ref.setField(packet,"a",uuid)
            ref.setField(packet,"b",action)
            ref.setField(packet,"c",IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer.a(message)?: "")
            ref.setField(packet,"d",progress)
            ref.setField(packet,"e", BossBattle.BarColor.a(color.id))
            ref.setField(packet,"f",BossBattle.BarStyle.a(style.id))
            ref.setField(packet,"g",darkenSky)
            ref.setField(packet,"h",playMusic)
            ref.setField(packet,"i",createFog)

            if (player != null) {
                (player as CraftPlayer).handle.playerConnection.sendPacket(packet)
            } else {
                for (player1 in this.getPlayers()) {
                    (player1 as CraftPlayer).handle.playerConnection.sendPacket(packet)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: ReflectiveOperationException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }

    override fun getMaxHealth(): Float {
        return 100F
    }

    override fun setHealth(percentage: Float) {
        setProgress(percentage / 100F)
    }

    override fun getHealth(): Float {
        return getProgress() * 100F
    }

    override fun getReceiver(): Player {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    override fun getLocation(): Location {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    override fun updateMovement() {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this specific case by doing

```
private fun argTypes(vararg args: Any): Array<Class<*>> {
    val argTypes = args.map { it::class.javaPrimitiveType ?: it::class.java }
    return argTypes.toTypedArray()
}
```

but then this wouldn't find a constructor which expects `java.lang.Float`.

Simply put: if you know the actual arguments for a constructor/method, there are many options for the types in the signature, so trying just one (as `fun argTypes` does) can't possibly work in general. In addition to the problem you ran into, the declared parameter type could be a supertype of an argument's class, the constructor could have varargs, etc.

A possible solution is just to get all constructors, feed your arguments to them and use the first one which doesn't throw an exception. You still need to be careful about varargs. Whether the performance cost is acceptable will depend on your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i will try it as soon as.